# Why do the "dietary supplement" pill bottles always have this bizarre disclaimer on them?

Tags: diet, supplement, pill

On every bottle of "dietary supplement" pills I've ever had, it says somewhere something along the lines of: "Dietary supplement pills are not a substitute for a varied and healthy diet."

Huh? Isn't the whole **point** of "dietary supplement" pills that they **are** a substitute for a "varied and healthy diet"? If one were already eating a varied and healthy diet, why in the world would they need the "dietary supplement" pills in the first place?

They appear to be literally stating that there is no point in buying and consuming their pills.

Comment: Unfortunately, this post was flagged as spam by automated spam detectors, which is why it has a -6 score. Please ignore the score.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the [meaning of the word "supplement"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dietary%20supplement):

> **Definition of dietary supplement**
>
> : a product taken orally that contains one or more ingredients (such
>   as vitamins or amino acids) that are intended to supplement one's diet
>   and are not considered food

The very meaning of the word means to "add to" so I don't think their disclaimer is unreasonable. Nobody can survive on supplements alone and even careful diets can be deficient in certain elements.